# Bun.js unable to import uuid in ESM project

Tags: es6-modules, bun

I have a simple nodejs project that used esm
I am trying to check whether I can replace the node with BunJS@1.0

BunJS is throwing an error.

Depicting a simple runnable example here

**Setup project**

```
npm init -y
npm i uuid esm
```

**index .mjs**

```
import uuid from 'uuid'
console.log("New UUID:", uuid.v4())
```

**Execution with Node [WORKING FINE]**

```
node -r esm index.mjs 
New UUID: f3284030-2f8f-4a39-af2d-1cc897331c4d `
```

**Execution with Bun [NOT WORKING]**

```
bun index.mjs 

SyntaxError: Missing 'default' import in module '/Users/sravankumarrekandar/workspace/bun-esm-uuid/node_modules/uuid/wrapper.mjs'.
```

```
bun run index.mjs 

SyntaxError: Missing 'default' import in module '/Users/sravankumarrekandar/workspace/bun-esm-uuid/node_modules/uuid/wrapper.mjs'.
```

I am new to bun.js. And trying to adapt it. I tried to find content about making existing nodejs projects run with bun. But seems there is not much content available.

I am expecting a way that I can keep my nodejs project code as it is but replace the run time

Answer (score 0):

For generating a uuid you can use: `crypto.randomUUID();`.

This will work in `bun` and a browser environment.
In `node` you need the additional import `import * as crypto from 'node:crypto';`.

Thus this code is not 100% platform independent.
But you can run the import conditionally like:

```
let nodeCrypto;
if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.versions && process.versions.node) {
  nodeCrypto = require('node:crypto');
}
```

and then use it like so:
`nodeCrypto ? nodeCrypto.randomUUID(); : crypto.randomUUID();`